# count and print array in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

Count of array is 5, I want to show only 3 result on page and want to show remaining on other page by giving view more link. But I can't figure out how to do it. I did it like this

```
if(count($claim) > 3)
    {
        $this->Html->link('View More>>>',array('controller'=>'User','action'=>'allclaimdisplay','id'=>$User['User']['id']));
    }
```

But it is showing 5 results but not showing display link(limit to get result in controller is 5)

Comment: can we have little more code that you have used?

Answer (score 0):

```
$displayLimit = 3;

for ($i=0; $i <= $displayLimit; $i++) {
    // print item here
}

if (count($claim) > $displayLimit) {
    $this->Html->link('View More>>>',array('controller'=>'User','action'=>'allclaimdisplay','id'=>$User['User']['id']));
}
```

Comment: I have tried it. but i have for each loop ,so am not able to use foreach loop inside for loop

Comment: I can not print my array without foreach loop